# How can I set the point size in a ggplot2 scatterplot to match the scale of the axes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scale, geom-point

I am trying to make a scatterplot using `ggplot2` in which the diameter of the points is of the same dimensions as the variables on the axes and should have the same scale. This problem is laid out well in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408977/how-to-adjust-the-point-size-to-the-scale-of-the-plot-in-ggplot2) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908147/geom-point-control-radius-exactly-rather-than-scaling-it), which was resolved by drawing ellipses on the graph (nowadays done with `geom_circle` from `ggforce`. However, for my application I need to draw thousands of points, which is quick using `geom_point` but *very* slow using `geom_circle`. Is there a way to scale `geom_point` to the scale of the axes?

As an example of the problem, this graph shows the discrepancy in scales using `scale_radius`:

```
x <- runif(20, 0, 20)
y <- runif(20, 0, 20)
radius <- runif(20, 0, 4)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, size = radius)

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(
    data = df,
    mapping = aes(
      x = x,
      y = y,
      size = radius
    )
  ) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_fixed() + xlim(0, 20) + ylim(0, 20) + 
  scale_radius(range = c(min(radius), max(radius)))

p
```

[image]

I have tried using `scale_radius` and `scale_continuous`, but both use a scale that is arbitrary with relation to the axis scales (`scale_radius` also does not scale such that a point of size 0 displays with size 0). I had the idea of accessing the plot size using `ggplot_build` and scaling the point sizes accordingly. I can access the plot range using `ggplot_buil(p)$layout$get_scales(i=1)` or `layer_scales(p)`, but no variables appear to correspond to the size of the plot in the units that `scale_radius` uses.

Comment: What do you mean by "scale ... to the scale of the axes"?  Do you want to adjust the *diameter* or the *area* of the point?  (I believe *area* is generally regarded as better.  Does `size = y` or `size = x` give you what you want?  If not, why not?

Comment: I don't think there is a straighforward way with `geom_point` since the render size will vary with the output resolution of your graphics device (downstream of ggplot2), so you'd have to use a manual magic number for each output resolution. I'd suggest trying `ggforce::geom_circle(n = 20)` or whatever low `n` you can get away with. The default is 360 which looks good for large sizes but will be overkill for thousands of points.

Comment: @Limey What I mean is that `radius` has the same dimensions as `x` and `y` - in this case distance, but this would also apply for uncertainties, etc. - so I want a point of `radius = 2`, for example, to be drawn with a radius of the distance that is 2 on the `x` and `y` axes. Using `size = x` would scale each point according to where it is on the axis, not by `radius`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 2000 circles and max radius of 1 (ie max diameter 2), I get a ~5-7x speedup using a lower poly resolution per circle. You might also look at your output device and try `ragg`, which is faster than cairo still offers nice anti-aliasing.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = radius)) +
  ggforce::geom_circle(n = 20) + #5-7x faster than default
  coord_fixed()
```

Still looks pretty good, with 1.5 sec render time on my system.

[image]

(You might also consider defining your plot window range using `coord_fixed(xlim = c(0,20), ylim = c(0,20))` since that will have the effect of zooming in on that viewing window instead of cropping out all data points out outside it, as your `xlim()` and `ylim()` (shortcuts for `scale_x_continuous(limits = ...)` and `scale_y_continuous(limits = ...)`. It's not an issue for `geom_point` but for `geom_circle` your approach will result in cut-off circles.)